# WordPress: Input Box displays Input data on the next page

Tags: php, wordpress

How to:

- Add an Input Text Box on my homepage
- The website visitor fills the box, submits
- He is redirected to a page on which the text he wrote in the box is displayed on screen

Comment: look like a homework question to me. You need to look at forms, form action, echo and/or print_r functions.

Comment: That's the thing, I'm not sure where to start, especially how to deal with cookies / transients.

Comment: Please start by googling for individual aspects first. I think this question is too broad/generic to have an „accepted answer“. You could do most this with a plug-in like contact form 7 or forminator, or write your own plugin, or do all of it in JavaScript...

Comment: Should I lean toward forms + transients (I use Avada), or JavaScript?

Comment: That depends on your use case. If the server needs to process to value, use a regular form. If you only need to populate the next page, you could store the value in localStorage in the browser